# Cropped Ad on iOS using firebase_admob plugin on flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-layout, ads, firebase-admob

Sadly, AdMob has 'restricted ad serving' to my iOS app because of odd plugin behaviour.

This is what they say on *Policy center*:

> MODIFIED ADS: Publishers are not permitted to alter the behavior of
>   Google ads in any way. This includes resizing ad frames to cut off
>   parts of ads or hiding the Ads by Google moniker.

I'm using latest firebase_admob: 0.9.3 version.

Size is set to AdSize.smartBanner.

Notice on the left edge how ad is cropped.

[image: cropped ad by firebase_admob]

Ad implementation is the standard one:

```
 void startBanner() {

  myBanner = BannerAd(

  adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (...)
}
void displayBanner() {
  myBanner
    ..load()
    ..show(
      anchorOffset: 0.0,
      anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
    );
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
   myBanner?.dispose();
   myInterstitial?.dispose();
   super.dispose();
  }
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();

   FirebaseAdMob.instance
     .initialize(appId: Platform.isIOS ? "ca-app-XXX" : "ca-app-YYY");

   startBanner();
   displayBanner();
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code implementation of the ad.

Comment: @i6x86, I've added. Thanks

Comment: And what happens if you set anchorOffset 10? Did you tried it, to see if this way it displays the banner correctly?

Comment: Or you can remove it at all. If it’s 0.0.

Comment: Doesn't work. The problem is with smartBanner size. If I choose largeBanner the ad is ok.

Comment: the banner implementation looks fine, it must be something with your code.